# How to get average sum for every weekday? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, average

I'm struggling with one task - I need to get average number of users for every weekday. Unfortunately, I'm stuck at this point.

```
SELECT dayname(DAY) as week, SUM(VISITORS_NUMBER) as vis
FROM mytable
GROUP BY week
```

The result of code above looks like this [Sum results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LXps.png)

From this moment I want to get same weekday column but with average values.

What can I do? I've tried subqueries, but I'm still a beginner and can't use it properly

Edit 1:
AVG() is not working. I'm getting results like this: [AVG() RESULTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dD9ao.png)

I checked in excel, average for friday should be 572, not 53.

That's how my dataset looks like: [Data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87eWH.png)

edit 2:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
 `DAY` date NOT NULL,
 `BROWSER` varchar(22) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `PLATFORM` varchar(13) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `VISITORS_NUMBER` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

INSERT INTO mytable(DAY, BROWSER, PLATFORM,VISITORS_NUMBER)
VALUES('2020-02-01','Android Webkit Browser','Android','9'),
       ('2020-02-01','Safari','iOs','5'),
       ('2020-02-01','Android Webkit Browser','Android','15');
```

Comment: Hint:  `AVG()`, not `SUM()`.

Comment: AVG() is not working, beacuse i'm getting strange average for day. I'll post 2 more pictures to precise my question

Comment: Show source data (as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts) and desired result for this data.

Comment: @Veticus . . . You are going to need to show some sample data and desired results.

Comment: @Veticus Can you please also show the print the number of weekdays?
Because here we have the sum for no. of visitors on let's say "Friday". But how many Fridays were there?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Updated with code

Comment: @ManishSundriyal Now i'm looking at this result and something is wrong. There are:
Friday - 91
Monday - 101
Saturday - 112
Sunday - 96
Thursday - 103
Tuesday - 96
Wednesday - 101

Comment: @Veticus
I am having a feeling that maybe the data is wrong either in DB or in excel.
Because you have mentioned that its of 2 months' data. So it is not possible to have so many weekdays in that period of time.

Considering that there are 4 weeks in a month, so each weekday will appear 4 times in a month. So try dividing your sum data by 8 for 2 months of data.
This way you can check how close your answer is, from the excel values.

Answer (score 0):

Test

```
SELECT DAYNAME(`day`) as `week`, SUM(visitors_number) / COUNT(DISTINCT `day`) as avg_vis
FROM mytable
GROUP BY `week`
```

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work - average for friday with your method is 1208, while it should be  572

Comment: @Veticus Replace the photo of the dataset with textual scripts (or create a fiddle). *average for friday with your method is 1208, while it should be 572* Obtain SUM and COUNT separately, check what value is wrong, and look why it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(t.day) AS day, AVG(t.visitors) AS vis
FROM (
  SELECT day, SUM(VISITORS_NUMBER) AS visitors
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY day
) t
GROUP BY DAYNAME(t.day)
```

See a simplified [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/voPwKUyP76FovY8tWsD7yR/0).

Comment: And it's still wrong - I'm getting result 1208 for friday instead of 572 :c

Comment: Run the code again as it is edited now. You can see in the demo that it works.